# Implementing event triggered action on Filezilla FTP server

Tags: triggers, ftp, task

I am using an opensource Filezilla FTP server that does not support event triggered actions. I want to build a component for handling the rules, based on the file creation event in a folder that will be monitored.What initial steps do I need to follow to get started?

Comment: What open source SFTP server? OpenSSH?

Comment: I am using Filezilla server.

Comment: Filezilla is not SFTP server. It's FTP/FTPS server.

Comment: It supports both, SFTP and FTPS

Comment: No, it does not. https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server *Support for SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not implemented in Filezilla Server.*